# I have an HDD that was taken from a Windows laptop, is there anything on the HDD which will indicate the model, manufacturer and OS of that laptop?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

The laptop in question is no longer available. I have the HDD in an enclosure and attached to a separate machine.

Here is a top level view of that drive:

[image]

Comment: You could try mounting the appropriate hive registry, and viewing the key, that typically holds manufacturer information

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound, but nothing on the Disk Identifiers (independent of data on the disk)

Comment: So by the way, that disk has bad sectors, hence the found folders and the recovery folder. Why do you care about the manufacture of the old system(

Comment: @Ramhound post your first comment as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2):

You will find this information from the registry hives, located
in various folders under `X:\Windows`, where `X:` is the
designation of the disk,

The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive is located under
`X:\Windows\System32\Config` and
contains information about hardware.
Every branch under this key is stored in a separate hive file.

You will find the computer model in registry key
`\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\HardwareConfig\Current\ComputerIds`.
Other keys will give more information about the hardware.

The SYSTEM hive file has the name of "SYSTEM".

To mount the SYSTEM hive :

- Run `regedit`
- Click to select `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
- Click menu *File > Load Hive...*
- Select the file to load and browse it.

Answer (score -2):

with powershell, you could have these information easily

```
# Gathering Disk information
Get-Disk  | select *
# Gathering OS information
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select *
```

Comment: This would only query the system information not the information from the HDD in question. Did you use ChatGPT to generate this answer, since only ChatGPT, would be unable to tell the difference and understand the contextual difference between a Windows installation on another drive?

Comment: I do apologize for the very strong statement, but the lack of understanding what the author desired, really comes down to a contextual understanding of the difference of how to query this information on the active systems registry and understanding which registry hive contains it. Since only a human would understand the difference, the fact this script would query the active systems registry hive, suggests that contextual understanding was lacking.

Comment: Sorry for that if i haven't understand the question. No I haven't use any IA to provide an answer (if it that the case, the IA answer will be Get-WMI Object .... deprecated since PS v3 :-) ). An explanation for that ? Perhaps because english is not my mother tongue.

Comment: The English in your answer is fine, the fact the answer, doesn’t answer the question is the problem. If you don’t understand the question seek clarification from the question author. If English isn’t your mother tongue, it’s still your responsibility, to understand the author’s question before answering it. In my opinion it’s a knowledge question.